# Self-referential database querying in flask-sqlalchemy. Social media application

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a social media web application and i have created a model called User which has two relations Posts (This works fine), and Friends (self-referential). I have migrated the database and it runs fine. I have also added followers via a database browsing tool, and it works well.

```py
friendship = db.Table(
    "friendships",
    db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), index=True),
    db.Column("friend_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id")),
)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    friends = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=friendship,
        primaryjoin=id == friendship.c.user_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == friendship.c.friend_id,
    )

    def follow(self, friend):
        if friend not in self.friends:
            self.friends.append(friend)

    def unfollow(self, friend):
        if friend in self.friends:
            self.friends.remove(friend)
```

I have wrote a simple query that finds who the User is following. This works fine.
`following = current_user.friends`

I am trying to write a query to list who follows the user (Similar to common social media apps such as Instagram) but I am struggling with the query. Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

`followers = db.session.query(friendship).filter_by(friend_id=current_user.id)`

Another issue I have is writing a query to find who the user is currently not following.

I'm not very experienced with databases, which is why I am struggling with these queries.
Thanks in advance for any help. I have also tried looking at similar posts but none of them are quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe something like this

followers = db.session.query(friendship).filter(friendship.friend_id == user_id).join(User, User.id == friendship.friend_id).all() (I might have swapped friend_id/user_id)

Comment: I have tried adding this line in and it causes the following error ```AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'friend_id'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a query to join the table to an aliased version of itself. [SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/self_referential.html#self-referential-query-strategies)

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

user_id = ... # id of the user whose followers you want to find

UserAlias = aliased(User)
followers = User.query.join(UserAlias.friends).with_entities(UserAlias).all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
    `followers = User.query.join(UserAlias.friends).with_entities(UserAlias).filter_by(id=current_user.id)` Is what i ended up using. Much appreciated!

Comment: @con_w No problem! One comment on your solution: I would advise against using `filter_by` in joined queries as it's not clear whether you are filtering on `User.id` or `UserAlias.id`